# Installing the gem system_timer on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Has anybody here successfully installed the `system_timer` gem on Windows?
I have `devkit` on my machine and I am able to install other native gems.
I get the following error when I install the gem.

```
In file included from system_timer_native.c:2:
c:/Ruby19/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: 
    #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
system_timer_native.c: In function `install_timer':
system_timer_native.c:28: error: storage size of 'timer_interval' isn't known
system_timer_native.c:33: warning: implicit declaration of function `sigprocmask'
```

The gem [home page](http://systemtimer.rubyforge.org/) states that it doesn't work on Windows

```
SystemTimer  only works on UNIX platforms (Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris, BSD, …). 
You can install the gem on Microsoft Windows, but you will only get a 
convenience shell wrapping a simple call to timeout.rb under the cover.
```

I am on Ruby 1.9, Since the threading model is different in 1.9, I am wondering if gem will work in 1.9.

Comment: /me tips hat to KandadaBoggu. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with Ruby's threading system, it's with the Windows kernel's timer system, I believe.

> System Timer, a timer based on
>   underlying SIGALRM system timers, is a
>   solution to Ruby processes which hang
>   beyond the time limit when accessing
>   external resources. This is useful
>   when timeout.rb, which relies on green
>   threads, does not work consistently.

You are better off asking directly the makers of the gem whether they have support for Windows+1.9 in the pipeline (if it's possible at all).